# <head> dinámico con php

Tags: php

Pues mirar, me gustaría utilizar en mi proyecto algo como:

```
require 'html_head.php';
```

Pero necesito funcione de manera diferente dependiendo de la sección de la web en la que este.

Por ejemplo 'registrar.php' necesita registrar.css, pero 'index.php' no lo necesita así que no quiero que 'html_head.php' lo incluya.

Ese solo es un ejemplo. Lo mismo me complica otras cosas como el titulo de la página, como la descripción, la inclusión de otros tipos de scripts, etc etc.

¿Me podeis decir como puedo programar esto?

Comment: Con variables booleanas.

Comment: Podrías tener alguna variable global que definas antes de llamar al include, donde especifiques en qué página estás para saber qué incluir, y dentro de html_head.php leas esta variable. Otra posibilidad es que el include tenga una función que debas llamar pasándole por parámetro la página en la que estás.

Comment: muchas gracias por su atención, hoy mismo voy a implementarlo :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes hacer algo así:

```
// index.php
$page = 'index';
require 'html_head.php';
```

```
// registrar.php
$page = 'registrar';
require 'html_head.php';
```

```
// html_head.php
if ($page == 'index') {
    // código para index
} elseif ($page == 'registrar') {
    // código para registrar
} elseif ($page == 'otra_pagina') {
    // código para otra página
} else { ... }
```

Primero, en cada archivo, guardamos en `$page` el nombre de la página, y luego lo podemos utilizar en el archivo `html_head.php`.

Comment: Es perfecto JCAguilera funciona genial. Gracias.

Comment: Que bueno que te haya funcionado, por favor marca la respuesta como correcta. Gracias!

Comment: Ya esta ! Un saludo JC.